# Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]) caused by async keyword

Tags: reactjs, async-await

I have got a pretty simple code sandbox sample here where I load a Loading ..  message then a Hello World.

```
const delay = (t) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, t));

export async function getMessageAPI() {
  await delay(1000);
  return Promise.resolve("Hello, World!");
}

export default async function AsyncMessage() {
  const [message, setMessage] = React.useState(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const result = await getMessageAPI();
      console.log(result);
      setMessage(result);
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  if (!message) {
    return "Loading...";
  }

  return <div>{message}</div>;
}
```

I kept getting the error with the snippet above:

```
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise])
```

And for the longest time, I thought there was something wrong with my promise setup. Eventually, I found my mistake was having the async keyword in

`export default async function AsyncMessage() {`

Once I removed that keyword then everything is fine. I know I don't need it now (I was putting await somewhere in the body of the component before).

**Question** Can someone explain why did I get such a cryptic error for this case, instead of don't use 'async' here?

```
import React from "react";

export default async function AsyncMessage() {
  return <div>hello</div>;
}

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise])
```

Comment: Because React doesn't care that you used an `async` function specifically; a non-`async` function returning a promise would be a problem for exactly the same reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can someone explain why did I get such a cryptic error for this case, instead of don't use 'async' here?

React has no way to know that you used the `async` keyword. It just knows you returned a promise from rendering, which isn't supported. Maybe that promise was created by an `async` function, maybe not.

So it does what it can: tells you that you can't return objects (promises are objects), and then logs the object that caused the problem.

Comment: Thanks, but in my function return, I am returning just a div `<div>hello</div>`, and not a promise though? I read that the word “async” before a function means one simple thing: a function always returns a promise. So does putting async automatically wrap the return value you specify in a promise, causing this error?

Comment: Yes, `async` functions always return promises. The promise will resolve to whatever value you return in your code. The `async` and `await` keywords exist to give us a more convenient syntax for working with promises.